# Comparing stability of 1,3-dioxolan-2-ide and 1,3-dithiolan-2-ide carbanions

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, heterocyclic-compounds, ring-strain

I'd like to compare stability of 1,3-dioxolan-2-ide and 1,3-dithiolan-2-ide carbanions:

[image: 1: 1,3-dioxolan-2-ide; 2: 1,3-dithiolan-2-ide]

I think there is no mesomeric or hyperconjugation effect and we should consider inductive effect.

Oxygen is more  electronegative compared to sulfur, and therefore should pull the electron cloud in a better way to stabilise the carbanion. Also, as sulfur is bigger in size, therefore I think it would also destabilise the ring creating some strain, resulting in **1** being more stable.

But the answer says that **2** is more stable. Where am I wrong?

Comment: While the acidity of 1,3-dithiolane is greater than 1,3-dioxolane at C2, it is nonetheless susceptible to fragmentation. That  is why 1,3-dithiane, the 6-membered ring is used as an umpolung  reagent.

Comment: sorry i am not familiar to umpolung reagent

Comment: Did you google "umpolung reagent"? Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey%E2%80%93Seebach_reaction

Comment: what happens if i take 1,3-dithiolane this as my reagent? will it not give hydrolysis or some other bond will be broken?

Comment: Hydrolysis of 1,3-dithiolane (Hg++, Ag+, etc.) will give formaldehyde and 1,2-ethanedithiol. What is unsuccessful is to attempt tp form the 2-lithio species and do an alkylation with, say 1-bromopropane, with the intent of forming n-butyraldehyde after hydrolysis. The anion fragments to ethylene and the "thioacetaldehyde" enolate. The fragmentation does not occur with 2-lithio-1,3-dithiane.

Comment: I almost understood everything ,but what is "thioacetaldehyde enolate".is it(https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Thioacetaldehyde), if yes i am not able to figure out how ethylene forms, if possible please provide me with the reaction.Thanks!

Comment: My bad! The sulfur entity is not the enolate of thioacetaldehyde but rather H(C=S)S-. Just push the electrons from C2 around the ring and ethylene will pop out.

Comment: oh got it ,thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a theoretical answer with electronic effects. Deciding stability involves on number of factors.

> I think there is no mesomeric or hyperconjugation effect and we should consider inductive effect.

Your assumption was incorrect. Because sulfur has vacant d-orbitals so that electrons from carbon can be involved in delocalisation with these vacant orbitals. So here sulfur acts as an electron withdrawing group which stabilises the negative charge on carbon.

Whereas this effect was not observed in case of oxygen since it doesn't have vacant orbitals. So oxygen can only exhibit −I effect on carbon. Therefore **2** is more stable than **1**.